# Dojo FilteringSelect - disable an item

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is it possible to disable an item from a FilteringSelect using a store?
The documentation shows an example of disabling an item, but only if HTML markup is used, and nothing is mentioned about select widgets using a datastore.
Looking at the source doesn't give any clues either.
If it matters the version of dojo used is 1.9

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951503/how-to-disable-a-single-option-in-a-dijit-form-select/17954286#17954286

Comment: This answer uses filtering of the `option` nodes, which aren't present if a store is used.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to disable an option of a filtering select, reason being that the item may not be present in the list when you type something in the textbox. Given the use case is to filter a list of items by typing in the textbox... why don't you just remove the unwanted item from your store ? Also, where in the doc did you see the example of disabling an item in a FilteringSelect with option tags ?

Comment: The item itself is not an actual choice, it's there only for presentation purposes. I'm trying to group the options(and need a title for each group), which is not supported at all.

Comment: I answered a similar question yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737418/dojo-1-9-dijit-disabling-option-items-in-a-dijit-form-filteringselect-that-was/18737965#18737965

Comment: [Here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Select.html) in the fourth example there is a select widget with a disabled option. [Here too](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/selects_using_stores/demo/ProgSelectOptions.html).

Comment: @DimitriM Could you answer this one too? :)

Comment: O sorry, I notice they don't implement the same API. I will see if I find an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After viewing at the source code I notice that `dijit/form/Select` extends from `dijit/form/_FormSelectWidget` which in fact makes it possible to retrieve and disable options in a select.

`dijit/form/FilteringSelect` however does not extend from the same widget but rather from a normal `dijit/form/MappedTextBox` (because of the typing abilities). Because of this, I'm quite sure it's impossible to do it out of the box, using a store or not (I wasn't able to get it to work without a store and didn't find such an example at the reference guide).

If you really need such a feature, I would suggest looking at the code of `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`, `dijit/form/Select` and `dijit/form/_FormSelectWidget` and trying to extend from one (ore multiple ones) and implement these features by yourself. The only question I ask myself is that, if this functionality isn't implemented by default, there might be a reason behind it.

Comment: Yup - the source shows no clues of such functionality(disabling an item from a store). Does the idea of editing the menu item template make any sense?

Comment: That's only the template, you will also need to modify the menu item widget itself so it can handle the disabled state. I'm not sure if that will work (because I don't know how the disabled state is handled). FilteringSelect is much more "attached" to a store than the Select variant. If you type a text in your textbox, it will query your store and that has nothing to do with the menu item template (so you will have to do something there too to make the disabled state work).

Comment: Isn't clicking on the arrow on the right also used to query the store, but without a condition? And the results from this query are displayed in a menu dijit.